# Android RemoteService Unable to start Service Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I am trying to build a remote service to which I can bind to activities that will be used and created often. I think this is the best method for handling what it is I am trying to accomplish. I keep getting this error though.

**Unable to start service Intent { act=com.services.OverheadService } U=0: not found**

I would think something might be wrong with my manifest? But I don't see what, my manifest will be at the bottom of the related code here below.

Here is the Call within my onCreate() in my activity:

```
// TESTING SERVICE IMPLMENTATION TODO
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.services.OverheadService");
boolean ok = this.bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
Log.v("ok", String.valueOf(ok));
```

Here is the Connection method:

```
/** SERVICE IMPLEMENTATION TESTING **/
    private ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            // get instance of the aidl binder
            mRemoteService = IRemoteService.Stub.asInterface(service);
            try {
                String message = mRemoteService.sayHello("Mina");
                Log.v("message", message);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                Log.e("RemoteException", e.toString());
            }

        }
    };
```

And here is the Service Class:

```
package com.services;

import com.services.IRemoteService.Stub;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.RemoteException;

public class OverheadService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    // implementation of the aidl interface
    private final IRemoteService.Stub mBinder = new Stub() {

        @Override
        public String sayHello(String message) throws RemoteException {
            return "Hello " + message;
        }
    };

}
```

AndroidManifest where the service is being set:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <service
            android:name="com.services.OverheadService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/failed_load" >

            <!--
            intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.cdkdevelopment.BaseActivity" />
            </intent-filter>
            -->
        </service>
```

Comment: Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002351/android-doesnt-bind-the-service-message-unable-to-start-service-intent/43064446#43064446

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution and it was changing this in the onCreate

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, OverheadService.class);
boolean ok = this.getApplicationContext().bindService(serviceIntent,
    mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
Log.v("ok", String.valueOf(ok));
```