# Android doesn't bind the service - Message "> Unable to start service Intent"

Tags: android

**The main idea**

I have two applications. The service is located in one application, the client is located in the other application.

The problem is I cannot bound the service because it gives me the error:

> Unable to start service Intent { act=com.ccc.serviceaarfinal.WifiAARService pkg=com.ccc.serviceaarfinal } U=0: not found

Service manifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.ccc.serviceaarfinal">

<application
    ...
    <service
        android:name="com.ccc.serviceaarfinal.WifiAARService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.ccc.serviceaarfinal.WifiAARService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

Client connection attempt:

```
private void connectService() {
    serviceConnection = new RemoteServiceConnection();
    Intent i = new Intent("com.ccc.serviceaarfinal.WifiAARService");
    i.setPackage("com.ccc.serviceaarfinal");
    bindService(i, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

**What I tried so far**

*Notes:* 
 I run `adb logcat` to see if there was something else that could help me

I tried to run the project on another computer and still don't work

- I didn't rename the packages

I didn't rename anything

I also tried `android:name=".WifiAARService"`instead of`android:name="com.ccc.serviceaarfinal.WifiAARService"`

Another note. I've implemented the service connection:

```
private RemoteServiceConnection serviceConnection;
private IWifiAARService service;

class RemoteServiceConnection implements ServiceConnection {

    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder boundService) {
        service = IWifiAARService.Stub.asInterface((IBinder) boundService);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Service connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        service = null;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Service disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
}
```

I tried to follow this example https://www.sitepoint.com/aidl-for-sharing-functionality-between-android-apps/ and works for me just if I name the modules without any capital leter (weird, I know).

Answer (score 0):

From [Official Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

> **Caution**: To ensure that your app is secure, always use an explicit
>   intent when starting a Service and do not declare intent filters for
>   your services. Using an implicit intent to start a service is a
>   security hazard because you cannot be certain of the service that will
>   respond to the intent, and the user cannot see which service starts.
>   Beginning with Android 5.0 (API level 21), the system throws an
>   exception if you call bindService() with an implicit intent.

You should remove `intent-filters`
and you can use `ComponentName` to start a component in another process.

```
Intent intent=new Intent();
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.ccc.serviceaarfinal","com.ccc.serviceaarfinal.WifiAARService"));
     appContext.bindService(intent,mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but now gives me the error `Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.ccc.serviceaarfinal/.WifiAARService } U=0: not found
`. Anyway, I think i got closer

Comment: try to change name of service  to just `.WifiAARService`

Comment: `"You should remove intent-filters and you can use ComponentName to start a component in another process."` not really, you can still use `<intent-filter>` if it is used together with `Intent#setPackage`

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem! I just build the service application, but there is the need to RUN the application.